# Cannot seem to properly add objects to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, graphics

I primarily program in Java but I am taking a graphics course for which I need to use C++. I am trying to create an array of objects in order to loop through them and draw them to the screen, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to create this array. I have code now which does not produce any compiler errors, but it doesn't seem to work correctly either. The following code is at the top of my Main.cpp class:

```
Platform ground("wallstone.tga", 40, 16, 4, 144);
Platform platform1("wallstone.tga", 10, 16, 4, 20);
Platform platforms[2] = {ground, platform1}
```

When I try: `fprintf(stdout, "Size of platforms array: %d", sizeof(platforms)/sizeof(Platform));` it prints out 0.0.

I've tried several ways of creating this array and they all seem to produce errors or that same output of 0.0, so I'm not sure what's going on. If any more of my code is necessary I will certainly be willing to post it. Of course, if there is a better way of approaching this I am grateful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious how the `%d` format specifier resulted in `0.0`...

Comment: Side note : Why fprintf ? You can use printf.

Comment: Also, the correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%uz`, and anyways in C++ you should use `std::cout` instead of `printf()`.

Comment: I typed the code from memory and made a few mistakes, meant %f. And fprintf is just the one I know haha.

Comment: If you're not married to arrays, you might find the collection classes in the STL, like vector, easier to deal with.  Just sayin'.

Comment: "fprintf is just the one I know" -- apparently not quite. `%f` cannot be used with an integer.

Comment: I never posted on here cause people are such twats about little mistakes. hope you feel good about yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing everything right. My only guess is that `size_t` on your platform is larger than `int`, so providing a correct format specifier (`%z` instead of `%d`) may fix the problem:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Size of platforms array: %z", sizeof(platforms)/sizeof(Platform));
```

Comment: alternately, cast the expression to int: `(int)( sizeof(platforms)/sizeof(platforms[0]) )`

Comment: That was precisely the problem, thanks so much! My function that loops through the array still isn't working (I was hoping the size issue was the problem), but I'll keep working on it. I appreciate it.

Comment: @H2CO3 You're right, the format for `size_t` is `z`. I didn't realize that `size_t` has its own format now :) Thanks!